# simulate on Beamer the TexPower animation "slide by slide", working on evince/okular

Tags: beamer, viewers, animations, animate

I'm looking for ways to generate **small animations in Beamer** that are compatible with **open source PDF Viewers** like Okular & Evince.

All the solutions I found did not work, except one: open [this demo](http://texpower.sourceforge.net/doc/fulldemo.pdf) on slide 74, section 1.8 in full screen using Okular or Evince (does not work with Firefox) and enjoy. Would it be possible to adapt it to Beamer, for example, to move a point around a circle?

**NB**: I wrote this question at the beginning as a real question, but after some research I found a solution before I finished writing this question, so I wanted to share it.

Any other solution that is not/badly described in my answer is welcome, and do not hesitate to say which solution works with which program.

(to see the MWE, see my answer below)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a description of all possible solutions I see, if you have info about software compatibility or tips, do not hesitate to comment and/or add another answer.

### Use transition duration

Idea : draw consecutive beamers frame, and set a `\transduration` to create an automatic change of the current frame (like in a diaporama)

Good points :

- Works well with Okular and Evince
- Very simple to implement
- Works "everywhere" if you don't mind to manually keep holding down the -> key.

Bad points :

- The generated PDF has lot's of pages
- Sometimes if you took a too small transition time, it's hard to "come back" to the beginning of the animation.

Software not usable :

- Works "everywhere", but (at least) in the Firefox & Chrome PDF Viewer, mupdf, and in impressive, you need to manually keep holding down the key ->

Code :

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}     
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \transduration<1->{0.1}
  \center
  \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,0) circle (1);
    \foreach \frnb in {1,...,75}
    {
      \draw<\frnb>[fill=red] ({5*(\frnb-1)}:1) circle (0.2);
    }
    \draw[draw=none] (-1.3,1.3) rectangle (1.3,-1.3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### Multimedia and movies : not practical for small animation & not automated

Idea : Convert the tikz animation into a movie, and insert the movie using beamer `multimedia`.

Good points :

- Works on Okular (didn't test on Evince, but I think it works)
- Play/pause/loop options
- Can contain fast and complete animation, not especially build from tikz.

Bad points :

- Movies are heavy
- They cannot be embedded in the pdf so you need to copy them appart
- The conversion from tikz to movie is not really easy to do : I would write a Makefile which calls `ffmpeg` & `convert` each time I want to use it... (By the way if you know a way to do that by using only latex package I'm interested) I will try to write this Makefile when I have more free time.
- When they are lot's of small animations between each pause, using a movie is not practical.

### Animate package : not supported by Okular/Evince

Idea : use the `animate` package, but does not work with Okular/Evince.

Good point :

- Very powerfull, provides loop, play, pause...

Bad point :

- Works only in Adobe Viewer, not supported by Okular and Evince (needs Javascript)

### Flash/MediaN... Not supported into Okular/Evince

If I want to use flash animation, the support on Linux is still worst.